# Using finite state machines for lexical analysis

Tags: regular-languages

I'm a high school student and I'm passionate about everything language related - lexers, parsers, compilers, interpreters and so on. Some time ago I've written a calculator in Python (now willing to use a better language), which uses the Shunting yard algorithm and my own lexer.

So I want to start learning more about this topic and found this [Compilers course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ztX3TEzQPc&list=PLFB9EC7B8FE963EB8&index=15). I pretty much understand how RegExp are used to specify the language but when the professor started talking about finite-state machines I just got lost in all the theory.

So this is my question: How do I use DFAs and NFAs for lexical analysis ?
What does "state" mean in this context ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Any given machine has a number of "states", and each state has a particular behaviour. You can think of the state as being a bit like the program counter. However, your question as a whole is much too broad to answer on this site: essentially, what you're looking for is a textbook on automata theory. There are many lecture courses on that, too, and they'll explain automata in more detail than a typical compilers course would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of any parser is to verify that a sequence of characters is a string in a specific language [C, Python, whatever].  In principle, the parser can be written to inspect each character in the sequence directly, but the parser will be more comprehensible and efficient if built to inspect higher-level *lexical tokens* - names, numbers, quoted-strings, miscellaneous operator symbols, parentheses, etc.  This is where the scanner comes in.  The scanner is essentially a subroutine which the parser calls to read the raw character stream and extract & return the next lexical token.

The scanner is implemented as a DFA which recognizes any token.  Each token type has its own structure as a character sub-sequence, representable as a regular expression which in turn is translated to a simple DFA; for example: a name is (in most languages) a sequence of characters consisting of [letter] followed by zero or more [letter or digit].  The scanner combines the simple DFAs for these expressions into a single DFA for their union.  This is (conceptually) implemented as a simple two-dimensional table, where rows are indexed by character values and columns are indexed by DFA state numbers (actually the rows are usually indexed by character classes - e.g 'letter' instead of 'a', 'b', ...).

Each call to the scanner follows this process: Begin in a common start state (e.g 0), looking at the next character [in the I/O buffer].  Using the lookup table, calculate the next state and 'consume' the next character [typically this means copying the character into the next slot in a buffer].  Repeat until a final state is reached, then return an object identifying the type of lexical token and the value from the buffer.  Example: Suppose the scanner is called when the next few characters are 'foo '.  The machine will move from state 0 to state (say) 11 and copy 'f' to the buffer; then move from state 11 back to state 11 and copy 'o' to the buffer - twice (two 'o'-s); then seeing the space it will move to some final state (say) 12, and return from the call, returning the object [type = NAME, value = 'foo'].  The next call to the scanner will begin where the last ended, looking at that space.

Most scanners do a bit more than this, of course.  In languages with reserved words, when the scanner finishes reading the name, it will typically look up the name in a table of reserved words; if found, it will return an object representing that specific reserved word instead of a generic 'name' object.  The scanner will usually 'eat' all contiguous whitespace without returning any token; similarly for comment text.  And so on and so forth....